# Where am I making a logic error while increasing the index value?

Tags: python

I'm developing software that tests strategies by scanning the bar values of cryptocurrencies. The software simulates the opening of a position when a situation I want occurs by reading the bars one by one. The index value indicates which bar I am reading at that moment. But as a result of the tests, I realized that the position is ignoring the bar just after the bar I opened. That's why I'm getting wrong results.

What is the reason for ignoring the next bar after I opened a position? Can you see where I am making a mistake?

Code:

```
ps_file = "files/ps-" + symbol.lower() + ".csv"

ops.run_strategy(datetime, math, time, csv, ps_file, symbol, candlesticks, candlesticks_len,
                         close_prices, rr_ratio, value, ema, macd, signal, rsi, upper, lower)
```

Functions

```
def run_strategy(datetime, math, time, csv, file_name, symbol, candlesticks, candlesticks_len,
                 close_prices, rr_ratio, xbar, ema, macd, signal, rsi, upper, lower):
    index = 0

    while index < candlesticks_len:

        direction = get_direction("rsi", index, close_prices, ema, macd, signal, rsi)

        if index == 0:
            clear_file(file_name)

        check_allowed = is_allowed(direction, index, close_prices, candlesticks, macd, signal, rsi, upper, lower)

        if direction == "buy" and check_allowed == True:
            index = open_position(datetime, math, time, csv, file_name, symbol, direction, index, candlesticks,
                                  close_prices, rr_ratio, xbar)

        if direction == "sell" and check_allowed == True:
            index = open_position(datetime, math, time, csv, file_name, symbol, direction, index, candlesticks,
                                  close_prices, rr_ratio, xbar)

        index += 1

def open_position(datetime, math, time, csv, file_name, symbol, direction, index, candlesticks, close_prices,
                  rr_ratio, xbar):
    ts = int(candlesticks[index][0])
    dt_obj = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts / 1000)

    stop_loss = calc_stop_loss("xbar", direction, float(close_prices[index]), index, candlesticks, xbar)

    take_profit = calc_take_profit(direction, float(close_prices[index]), stop_loss, rr_ratio)

    leverage = calc_leverage(math, time, direction, float(close_prices[index]), stop_loss)

    save_position(csv, file_name, symbol, candlesticks[index][0], dt_obj, index, direction, leverage,
                  close_prices[index], take_profit, stop_loss, "e")

    index += 1

    while True:

        try:
            if direction == "buy":

                if float(candlesticks[index][3]) <= stop_loss:
                    pos_result = "LOST"
                    save_result(csv, file_name, pos_result)
                    return index

                if float(candlesticks[index][2]) >= take_profit:
                    pos_result = "WON"
                    save_result(csv, file_name, pos_result)
                    return index

            if index < len(candlesticks) - 1:
                index += 1
            else:
                return index

            if direction == "sell":

                if float(candlesticks[index][2]) >= stop_loss:
                    pos_result = "LOST"
                    save_result(csv, file_name, pos_result)
                    return index

                if float(candlesticks[index][3]) <= take_profit:
                    pos_result = "WON"
                    save_result(csv, file_name, pos_result)
                    return index

            if index < len(candlesticks) - 1:
                index += 1
            else:
                return index

        except Exception as e:
            return index
```

Example line 10 of the csv file. The index variable indicates which line we read

```
1631836800000,3.4311,3.4348,3.4128,3.4185,21701,1631837099999,74267.7900,412,11886,40673.5353,0
1631837100000,3.4191,3.4232,3.4122,3.4150,12947,1631837399999,44237.8548,272,3766,12865.3188,0
1631837400000,3.4167,3.4490,3.4153,3.4328,50973,1631837699999,175120.1143,498,22415,76932.7275,0
1631837700000,3.4329,3.4334,3.4239,3.4255,16417,1631837999999,56271.7909,231,11105,38067.8802,0
1631838000000,3.4243,3.4270,3.4159,3.4160,11105,1631838299999,37977.3639,174,4705,16092.3815,0
1631838300000,3.4160,3.4160,3.3871,3.3871,38991,1631838599999,132518.2692,369,3073,10450.5525,0
1631838600000,3.3872,3.4027,3.3852,3.3899,24696,1631838899999,83753.1764,311,11916,40391.6030,0
1631838900000,3.3907,3.3957,3.3861,3.3878,10555,1631839199999,35781.3135,213,5688,19278.9597,0
1631839200000,3.3872,3.3898,3.3758,3.3879,27350,1631839499999,92532.8729,296,20280,68618.0346,0
1631839500000,3.3886,3.3974,3.3858,3.3923,26058,1631839799999,88381.9005,236,15578,52830.4907,0
```

The values in the rows mean the following values

```
[
  [
    1499040000000,      // Open time
    "0.01634790",       // Open
    "0.80000000",       // High
    "0.01575800",       // Low
    "0.01577100",       // Close
    "148976.11427815",  // Volume
    1499644799999,      // Close time
    "2434.19055334",    // Quote asset volume
    308,                // Number of trades
    "1756.87402397",    // Taker buy base asset volume
    "28.46694368",      // Taker buy quote asset volume
    "17928899.62484339" // Ignore.
  ]
]
```

Comment: Please, provide a sample data to make the problem reproducible.

Comment: The csv file I'm working on has over 2000 lines so I added a 10 line example

Comment: Have you tried setting up logging?  What happens if you add some `elif` statements to your functions instead of all `if-else`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Comment: I couldn't see a section suitable for using `elif`, where do you think I should use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the risk of getting a ton of minuses and without running any code or debug, what I see is this condition:

```py
if index < len(candlesticks) - 1:
```

it exists twice with the same indentation. When it evaluates to true, it increments `index` twice.